# How to use the function shell_exec() PHP

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a problem with the function shell_exec(), i've tried everything but I don't know where is the problem. I have this php program that verificates if you are logg in or not, I wanted to use a cookie but i'm not allowed in the apache server of the company where i'm working I don't know why. So normally in this program I check if I have already initiated my session, if I don't, I use a login that the user put it in a case of text in the page before, if I do (already initiated my session), I'll use the login that I put in the case of text before, now stocked in the session variable. I don't know if its the right way to do but thats the solution that I came with. I'm not an expert in php.
So the problem is that the function shell_exec() works outside the first "if"but not in the condition, when I get into the condition its returns me nothing. I would like to know your opinions.

This is the code:

```
     $login = $_POST['login_venezia'];

if (isset($login))
{

    $log = $login;

    if($_SESSION['login_test']!=NULL)
    {
       $tableau = shell_exec('groups'.$_SESSION['login']);
       echo "1";
       echo $_SESSION['login']."\n";
    }
    else
    {
       $tableau = shell_exec('groups'.$log); 
       echo "2";
       echo "Login = ".$log;
    }


    //$tableau = shell_exec('groups '.$log);
    echo "Login = ".$login;
    echo "Tableau = ".$tableau;
    $resultat = explode(" ",$tableau);
    $cookies = $_COOKIE['session_ser'];
    die;

    $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); //chemin avant de fichier courant
    $path_separe = explode('/',$path); //nous retourne la chaine de caractere donc le chemin du fichier mais sans les slash
    $lenght = count($path_separe);
    $imp = $path_separe[$lenght-2];

    if($tableau != NULL)
    {

        for($i=0; $i<count($resultat);$i++)
        {
            if($resultat[$i] === $imp && $cookies!=NULL)
            {
                $valeur = 1;
            }
        }
        if($i === count($resultat))
        {
            //header('Location: verifnon.php?mavar=1'); //n'appartien pas au projet
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //header('Location: compteinexistant.php?mavar=1'); //son compte existe pas  
        echo "Erreur";
    }


    if($valeur === 1)
    {
        session_cache_limiter('private');
        $cache_limiter = session_cache_limiter();

        /* Configure le délai d'expiration à 30 minutes */
        session_cache_expire(1440);
        $cache_expire = session_cache_expire();

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;

       //header('Location: verifoui.php?mavar=1'); 
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Veuillez saisir votre login \n";
}
```

Comment: Does it go inside `if` condition?

Comment: Yes, as you can see the variable $tableau its the one that receives the result of shell_exec() inside the condition if and else

Comment: did you try to run your command in your command prompt, 1st you have to check, it really working or not.

Comment: yes, the command works, and also works outside the first if and else, but inside it doesnt

Comment: Have you tried putting a space after groups? shell_exec('groups '.$log);

Comment: THATS IT, i didnt see it before, thank you very much

Comment: Examples should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a space after groups otherwise you are running 'groupslogin' which is not a command:

```
if($_SESSION['login_test']!=NULL)
{
   $tableau = shell_exec('groups '.$_SESSION['login']);
   echo "1";
   echo $_SESSION['login']."\n";
}
else
{
   $tableau = shell_exec('groups '.$log); 
   echo "2";
   echo "Login = ".$log;
}
```